# What is the minimum of x+y if xy=k, and where x, y are positive integers.

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

What is the $\min(x+y)$ if $xy=k$ and $x, y, k \in Z$. I've got this question from thinking of the minimum perimeter of a given area of a rectangle. Here's my try:

From AM-GM:
$x+y\le 2 \sqrt {xy}$

$\Rightarrow x+y\le \lceil 2\sqrt {k} \rceil$

$\Rightarrow x+y =\le \lceil 2\sqrt {k} \rceil$

From Veita's formula:

$t^2 -(\lceil 2\sqrt {k} \rceil)t +k$

And finally by the Quadratic formula:

$t=\frac {\lceil 2\sqrt {k} \rceil \pm \sqrt {(\lceil 2\sqrt {k} \rceil)^2 -4k}} {2}$

The Formula that I've got works fine with lots of numbers but not all of them (e. g: $k=5$ spits (3.618..., 1.381...)). Can you help me work this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If, say, $k=p$, a prime,  then you know that $(x,y)=(1,p)$ or $(p,1)$ so $x+y=1+p$.  In general, the answer will depend on the way $k$ factors (clearly).

Comment: Moreover, you've got the AM-GM inequality going the wrong way.

Comment: Conclude from the equality case in the AM-GM inequality: $x=y=\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As I said, if you require that $x,y\in \mathbb N$ then you need to address the factorization of $k$.

Comment: For example, if $k=100$ then $x=y=10$ because $x+y$ is the most least. And for $k=24$ we have $x=4$ and $y=6$ because $x+y=4+6=10$ is the most least.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain minimum perimeter. If you do it will be just a straight line with any of the $x,y=0$.

Where as you can obtain the Maximum perimeter by using the concept of derivatives. If you are interested to find this out, then let me know.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, check my examples that I've given to "Lulu" and you may understand the question more.